# how do I add development build number each time I compile and play?

Tags: java, slick

I wanted each time I play my game, it will show in the console how many times you compiled or run the game. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the question really is how do you compile your game:

- If you just use `javac` in the console, make a batch file (in whatever batching language your OS supports, i.e. .bat file for windows, .sh file for Linux, etc) that before executing the compiling command (or after) will read the current build number from a text file, increment it and re-write it;
- If you use a project build tool such as Ant or Maven, you can configure them to automatically place the build number (and build date, etc) into a specified text file.

Finally, whatever your approach, make your application code read the values in that text file and display them somewhere.

Comment: As to how many times you've played your game, just add code to the start of your game that increments a counter in a file..

Comment: If you do not yet use a build tool like ant or maven, you really should consider using it.